# How to dynamically set Datatables search and column filters state via url params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

Let's say I have two models: **customers** and **orders**.
Every order belongs to a customer.

I also set a orders (index) view with a Datatable showing all the orders.
If I want to see all the orders for a given customer all I have to do is to filter the results for that customer writing the concerning customer name in the "search" field or selecting that customer from its column filter field.

Now I'd like to implement a customer-orders link which automatically shows the orders Datatable with those settings.

In other words, I'd like that a link to /orders?isearch='customer_name+customer_surname' will show the Datatable with the customer full name already written in the search field (or the customer column filter set accordingly).

Of course I can fetch the **@customer** instance variable from the controller and pass it to the view, but *then*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the **oSearch** variable in the initialization code I can define an initialization value for the search field, the isearch variable:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  var isearch = $('#isearch').val()   

  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": isearch}
  } );
} )
```

The isearch value is stored in a proper hidden field in the view:

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "isearch", @isearch.to_s, { :id => "isearch" } %>
```

(**This is the best way I found so far to pass an instance variable to a .js file in Rails**).

Last but not least, the @isearch instance variable is set from the order_controller:

```
@isearch = params[:isearch]
```

Of course its value should be passed to the url like:

```
.../orders?isearch='customer_name+customer_surname'
```

**----ADDENDUM----**

I figured out I don't need an instance variable, in fact I can pass as many url params as I want using this javascript function:

```
function getUrlParam( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1].replace("+", " ");
```

}

Then I can fetch them from my .js file like this:

```
// fetches url params
var isearch = getUrlParam('isearch');
var customer_name = getUrlParam('customer_name');
var order_status = getUrlParam('order_status');
```

Accordin to these values I not only can set the oSearch variable but also a column-specific using Datatables **aoSearchCols** initialization parameter ( http://www.datatables.net/ref#aoSearchCols )

The last problem to solve, given that I am using individual column filtering with select elements (http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html), so set every select element according to the URL-passed params.
I did it with this jQuery instruction:

```
// sets all select filters according to url passed params
$('select').val([customer_name, preparation_kind, preparation_status]);
```

From the performance point of view this solution is improvable, but its easy and it works.